# error: unknown option `--port' in Pm2 manager node js

Tags: node.js, load-balancing, pm2

I am using the command to run app on different different port but I am getting error(error: unknown option `--port').
// command

```
pm2 start app.js -i 0 -- --port=1336
```

Comment: Do you intend to pass --port option to your own application?

Comment: Or do you expect pm2 to handle the port management for you?

Comment: yes,I want to run application on four different ports

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Which one is it? To clarify, --port is an option that you need to handle on your own in your app. If you expect, that pm2 is going to do that, you are wrong.